# Problemas ejecución Xampp

Tags: xampp

alguien sabes por qué Xampp tira estos errores al cerrar el administrador. Os dejo pantallazos.
He instalado Xampp en Windows 10, varias veces (instalado, desinstalado y vuelto a instalar), y no hay forma de que no me tire ese error.

Muchas gracias!!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Esto es problema de permisos; el archivo ini quedó de sólo lectura. Puedes borrar ese archivo para que xampp lo recree con los permisos correctos, o puedes ajustarle los permisos al archivo (o revisar incluso si C:\xampp tiene los permisos correctos, también):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que está relacionado con el error del exe, que es el encargado de meterle mano a ese archivo. De hecho, podríás probar con cambiarle el modo de ejecución a ese amigo para que no tenga líos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]